# How to implement set::find() to match only the key of a pair?

Tags: c++, stl, set, iteration

I have a container class which stores data in a `std::set`. I don't need or use the extended facilities provided by `std::map`. There is a method `values()` which returns a `const reference` to the private set so if I were to use a map instead then I would have to copy the entire container. I want to keep it as a `std::set`.

The set contains objects of a class similar to `std::pair` with a key and a value and implements `operator <` for use in a set.

I have a method in the container which accepts the 'key' portion of the pair for the purpose of searching the set and returning a complete pair while only matching the key.

I can iterate through the set sequentially but then I lose the O(log N).

Also note that the set needs to be sorted, which removes the option of using an `unordered_set`.

Comment: how `operator<()` is implemented?

Comment: *"I don't need or use the extended facilities provided by std::map"* seems like you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what your `operator<` actually compares, but the long and the short of it is that with a `std::set`, the only way to efficiently search the set is by using its defined comparison function.

Based on your question, I am assuming that your set is

```
std::set<std::pair<firstType, secondType>, ComparisonClass>
```

With `ComparisonClass` implementing the strict weak ordering. Or, your could also be using a:

```
std::set<PairClass>
```

With the `PairClass` being a subclass of a `std::pair`, that implements an `operator<`, for the strict weak ordering. Either one or the other is  what appears your question is describing. But either way, both alternatives are logically equivalent, for the purpose of the following answer:

If your `operator<` implements strict weak ordering based on both the value pair's `first` and `second`, then that's pretty much it. You can only execute the set's built-in logarithmic search by searching for the same `first` and `second`.

There's no easy way to do anything other than that. So, what now?

Well, the root problem seems to be is that you might not be using the right container. Consider the following container that, with a little bit of work, will be equivalent to your set:

```
std::multimap<firstType, std::set<secondType>>
```

That is, your container is a multimap keyed by your pair's `first`, with the value of your multimap being a `std::set` of all the `secondType` that are paired up with a given `firstType`.

The only thing you have to be careful here is to define insert and remove operation into this container in such a manner, so that you will never end up with a `firstType` with an empty `std::set` value. As long as this condition is met, this should be logically equivalent to a `std::set` of your `std::pair`s. Furthermore:

1) You can still implement an algorithmic search for a `firstType`+`secondType` by, first, a logarithmic search on the `firstType`, grabbing the value `std::set`, and then executing a logarithmic search on that. Logically equivalent.

2) You can implement an algorithmic search for just the `firstType` by doing only the first half of the full search. This gives you the value `std::set`, that provides the equivalent of all pairs that have the same `firstType`.